# Window manager stalling with specific mouse pointer shape after hitting Ctrl-Z

Tags: xorg, window-manager

I have had a complete stall of the X window manager which happened just as I was trying to stop a process with keystrokes. I wonder whether the cause of the stall can be identified, or whether I could have restored functionality with in a less harsh way than what I did.

**What brought the stall:** In a terminal, within an ssh session with a distant computer, I had started a process which I immediately realised was not what I indented and potentially harmfull. Specifically, I ran `bash script.py` rather than `python script.py`.
I pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, this displayed as `^C` but without giving me back bash prompt, so I also pressed  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> and possibly a few other <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>whatever</kbd>.

**Symptoms:** just after that, I realised I couldn't bring focus to any other terminal or window. Mouse pointer didn't have its usual arrow or I beam shape, but something like this:

[image]

Keystrokes like <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>arrow</kbd> to change workspace, those opening menus didn't work. I could switch to tty/1 using <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, running `top` there didn't reveal much (top process were `ssh`, `sshfs` and `cp` as I was running a backup in the background). I killed `firefox` just as a wild try.
Back in my X window session I tried some more interactions until I pressed <kbd>crl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>backspace</kbd> which ended graphic session. Logging back in, all worked properly.

**My question:** if it happens some next time, what can I do better?

Some details: debian bullseye, xfwm 4.16.1-1, xfce 4.14, xorg 1:7.7+22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer on the [AskUbuntu SE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031400/mouse-cursor-turned-into-a-thick-plus-cannot-click-but-mouse-can-move).

Indeed I had ran `bash` on a python script, starting with `import`, and as they explain

> `import` is the command to create a screenshot, provided by the ImageMagick tool suite. (...) Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, which is the shortcut for freezing a process and returning to the command prompt in Bash. So `import` is still "running" (not exactly - it's frozen, but still existing) and didn't get a chance to exit or return control over the mouse and screen.

Even through ssh, this can ask X to halt normal mouse and keyboard interaction it seems.

So what one should do is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, open a nes `ssh` connection to the remote computer and kill the `import` process. Alternatively, kill the `ssh` through which that process has been run.